# Can't get virsh list in node-ssh

Tags: node.js, ssh, virsh, node-ssh

app.js:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const {NodeSSH} = require('node-ssh')
const ssh = new NodeSSH()
ssh.connect({
    host: '192.168.0.2',
    username: 'ubuntu',
    password: '123456'
})
.then(function() {
    ssh.execCommand('virsh list --all', {}).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        return;
    })
})
```

Return:

```
Id  Name State
--------------------
```

But the command `virsh list --all` works and return complete list when using ssh connect via command line. I also test another command in app.js like `ls` or `pwd` , and works normally.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you sure the guest domains are running under the user "ubuntu"? Is it possible you're either logged in as root or prefixing the command with "sudo" when you are trying the command via your interactive SSH client?

Comment: Additionally it's possible that your interactive shell session startup script sets some environment variables that `virsh` is using. Non-interactive command execution via ssh does not execute these shell session startup scripts, so that could be another difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your command with:

```
bash -l -c "virsh list --all"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.